# Calculate and find the second day of the week in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Let's say I have data like this

| CustomerID | Trans_date |
| --- | --- |
| C001 | 01-sep-22 |
| C001 | 04-sep-22 |
| C001 | 14-sep-22 |
| C002 | 03-sep-22 |
| C002 | 01-sep-22 |
| C002 | 18-sep-22 |
| C002 | 20-sep-22 |
| C003 | 02-sep-22 |
| C003 | 28-sep-22 |
| C004 | 08-sep-22 |
| C004 | 18-sep-22 |

But I'm unable to find the first and second transaction based on Trans_date.
I wish for the result to look like this:

| CustomerID | Trans_week | first | second |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C001 | 35 | 35 | 37 |
| C001 | 35 | 35 | 37 |
| C001 | 37 | 35 | 37 |
| C002 | 35 | 35 | 37 |
| C002 | 35 | 35 | 37 |
| C002 | 37 | 35 | 37 |
| C002 | 38 | 35 | 37 |
| C003 | 35 | 35 | 39 |
| C003 | 39 | 35 | 39 |
| C004 | 36 | 36 | 37 |
| C004 | 37 | 36 | 37 |

And for the last result will show like this:

| CustomerID | first | second |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C001 | 35 | 37 |
| C002 | 35 | 37 |
| C003 | 35 | 39 |

C004 didnt include because i would need who cust id who come first in their 1st week.

Comment: Could you please share the sample output? and also please correct the DB Tags.

Comment: hii i just update my question and i put my sample result too. thankyou

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Comment: there's no bug, i just dont know how to calculating

Comment: I didn't say there was, I requested you to show your data as formatted text, not as images, and to correct your database tags.

Comment: Why Customer `C001` has first row `36` if trans week is `39` in your desired output ?

Comment: There is no DATEPART function in MySQL, I think you are using SQL Server, so you may correct your tag.

Comment: Why Customer C001 has first row 36 if trans week is 39 in your desired output ? because c001 have history buy some product in week 36, week 37 week 39. but i want find when c001 back again since c001 1st come in week 36. so the result i want is week 37. sorry for my bad explaining about my quest. btw i already saw ur prev comment, and it's right as what i need, but can if there's no duplicate ID?

Comment: I returned it back. You are talking about the last query ?

Comment: yes. the output like C001|week 36|week36|week37, C001|week 37|week 37, C001|week 38|week 37 ---- can it make the output not duplicate? like just C001|week 37| week 37? not show the first week and another week, just 2nd week?

Comment: You must Exclude column `Trans Week` or use some aggregate function for it. If you have three values for `Trans Wee` 36,37,38 and you want to show it once. Which value you will show. That's why in third query I've dropped that column

Comment: its possible i get not duplicate value if i delete transweek?

Comment: If you dele transweek you can `Group by CustomerID` same as i did in my third sql query.

Comment: i've tried it, but it looks like the second column still doesn't match. when C001 have transaction in week 36 37 39, hope the column "SecondWeek" will show 37 not 39. as well as other CustID, when C002 have transaction in week 36 37 38 39, it will show 37. and for C003 and C004 it's already as like what i hope

Comment: @tasyafauziafitriasari check my answer. Is this you want ?

Comment: almost... when id C002 colum SecondWeek, it's show week 37. for the other data (C001 C003 C004) its already right

Comment: @fasya fixed that part should be `> SRC.FirstWeek ` @tasya fauzia fitriasari

Answer (score 1):

```
with cte (RN,CustomerID, FirstWeek,SecondWeek ) as
( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by CustomerID  ORDER BY CustomerID  )  RN, CustomerID,FirstWeek, isnull((select TOP 1 (DATEPART(week,CustTrans))   
                from trydata c 
                    where c.CustomerID = SRC.CustomerID AND DATEPART(week,C.CustTrans) > SRC.FirstWeek  
                    ORDER BY DATEPART(week,C.CustTrans) ),'0')  AS SecondWeek 
FROM (  
    SELECT CustomerID,DATEPART(week,CustTrans) TransWeek,
      (select MIN(DATEPART(week,CustTrans)) from trydata c where c.CustomerID = trydata.CustomerID) AS FirstWeek
    FROM trydata
) SRC )

select CustomerID,FirstWeek,SecondWeek from cte where RN = 1
```

Output:

Example 2 :

```
WITH CTE (CustomerID,FIrstWeek,RN) AS (
    SELECT CustomerID,MIN(DATEPART(week,CustTrans)) TransWeek,
    ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by CustomerID  ORDER BY DATEPART(week,CustTrans) asc ) FROM TryData 
    GROUP BY CustomerID,DATEPART(week,CustTrans)
) 

SELECT CTE.CustomerID, CTE.FIrstWeek,  
     (select TOP 1 (DATEPART(week,c.CustTrans))   
        from trydata c 
            where c.CustomerID = CTE.CustomerID AND DATEPART(week,C.CustTrans) > CTE.FIrstWeek 
                )   SecondWeek 
FROM CTE  
WHERE RN = 1
```

[FIddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZMpJFMH8)

Edit: This can be done on easier way and less complex.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `ROW_NUMBER()` function -inside a subquery- to get the first and second transaction dates for a customer, then use conditional `MAX` window function on the results of that subquery.

```
SELECT CustomerID, DATEPART(week,CustTrans) AS Trans_week,
       DATEPART(week, MAX(CASE rn WHEN 1 THEN CustTrans END) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID)) first,
       DATEPART(week, MAX(CASE rn WHEN 2 THEN CustTrans END) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID)) second
FROM
  (
    SELECT *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY CustTrans) rn
    FROM trydata
  ) T
ORDER BY CustomerID, Trans_week
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/74LtrSGP) on SQL Server.

As you requested in the comments, if you want to select only one row per customer that showing the first and second weeks, use the following query:

```
SELECT CustomerID,
   DATEPART(week, MAX(CASE rn WHEN 1 THEN CustTrans END)) first,
   DATEPART(week, MAX(CASE rn WHEN 2 THEN CustTrans END)) second
FROM
  (
    SELECT *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY CustTrans) rn
    FROM trydata
  ) T
WHERE rn <= 2
GROUP BY CustomerID
ORDER BY CustomerID
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/c7h57nXq).

Comment: hii can possible if i want show only 1 data? ex. if c001 show on 2nd week in week 37 so i want it show just about c001 week 37 (no duplicate or show another week). and it's not only for c001 but all custID

Comment: Do you mean select all rows where second week =37? [check this query](https://dbfiddle.uk/GWOLLsKh)

Comment: no. it's like C001|week 36| week 37, C002|week 36| week 37, C003|week 36| week 40, C004|week 36|week 39..... so its just shown one data which they show fisrt week and 2nd week

Comment: Ok, I updated the answer according to that, you may check it.

Comment: but it looks like the second column still doesn't match. it is hoped that the second they come back will show, not their second history. example. C001 order in week 36 38 37 39. so the column name second will show week 37, not 38

Comment: I couldn't understand you, it would be better to edit your question and add the expected output of this scenario.

Comment: I updated about my question, thank you.

Comment: Have you checked the [second query](https://dbfiddle.uk/c7h57nXq) in my answer? It gives you exactly what you want !!!

Comment: @Ahmed Very clean. Good approach

Comment: @Ahmed i'm just trying your code, but the output will be null if the data isnt present in the 1st week.  does it support new data that isnt in the 1st weeks data to be lost? (not included in the output)

Comment: `WHERE rn <= 2 AND first IS NOT null`